# Laravel : Nothing to Migrate

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

so I have looked around and found several suggestions of how this can be fixed but I still can't get it to work.

so I have created a file called **social.php** inside my migrations folder.

and added this code inside it. but when I execute the command

> php artisan migrate

I get Nothing to migrate as a return.

Note that I executed this command to created Auth (*`users table`* and *`password reset`* migrated successfully), then after I finished with them, I backed them up and removed them from migration folder.

I created *`social.php`* and then all of this happened.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSocialTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('social', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('userid');
            $table->string('sname');
            $table->string('sud');
            $table->string('surl');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('social');
    }
}
```

Comment: So you deleted the default migrations after running the migration? Try deleting the migration table in your database, running `composer dump` and trying again. Failing that, delete the migration and create it using artisan on the command line: `php artisan make:migration create_social_table`.

Comment: tried it , I also tried composer dump-autoload but still nothing

Comment: Updated above comment.

Comment: Did you run this and initially fail? The migrate script will still update the migration table regardless. If you wrap the `Schema::create` in a try/catch, and rollback on failure in the catch, this should allow you to do it again

Comment: my mistake was making it manually instead with a command. got it to work. thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have you created the migration file via `php artisan make:migration` or you've created it manually?
2. If you did it through the command the just drop the respected table from your database and also delete your migration file then run `php artisan migrate`

Use this Command in Terminal For Make Migration:

```
php artisan make:migration create_social_table
```

if your looking for a model with migration just put

```
php artisan make:migration create_social_table -m
```

Comment: I have created it manually ,  Ill try making it with the command .

Answer (score 3):

To create a migration, use the *`php artisan make:migration`* Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_tablename_table
```

The new migration will be placed in your *`database/migrations`* directory.

After, To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Please create new folder in migration folder like **test** and put your(`social.php`) file in **test** folder and run below command in your terminal or cmd

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/test/
```

Comment: still nothing to migrate

Comment: my mistake was making it manually instead with a command.   got it to work. thanks for your time

Comment: Saurabh php artisan make:migration will help him to make migration just provide name to Migration

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in your console:

```
php artisan make:migration create_tablename_table
```

Comment: Hello friend, this has been answered already but thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

if you previously run the **php artisan migrate** and now you want to change migration without creating new alter migration for this table and want run again as a migration create but it is showing you **Nothing to migrate**.

to fix this just follow below steps

1. Open database and delete the table that you want change with changed migration.
2. write a query to delete a records

   select * from migrations order by id desc
3. check for your migration file in this result and delete this record
4. Run `php artisan migrate` command

Answer (score 0):

Command:**php artisan migrate**
Problem:Nothing to migrate.
First run command: **php artisan migrate:reset**
than run command: **php artisan migrate** table update new field added.

Answer (score 0):

i also run php artisan migrate but nothing to migrate eventhough i made change in up() function

and this command works to me

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```